# Coworker "promoted" to manager but not officially through HR

Tags: ethics, human-resources, promotion, colleagues

A coworker was given a title of Team Manager and I and my fellow employees are expected to report to this person instead of going to our official boss. However...it is an unofficial title (for now). This person will conduct our one-on-on meetings and team meetings and get to chime in on our evaluations and determine our workflow, etc.

I work in a very large corporation and all manager positions are competitive (you have to conduct interviews). That is why I think this person was just given an honorary title -- however, if and when the position comes available officially I'm sure they will just point to this person and say -- well, they are already doing the job so they have the experience and that makes them more qualified than you.

My question is -- is it ethical for a peer to "act" as your boss and rank or rate you? This co-worker is now the only person who has direct access to the official boss. Should I go to HR with my concerns? Or would I just be making waves. I have indicated my wish to be promoted to management.

Just to add another piece of info -- our team is located in three different states and this new Team Leader is a personal friend of the official boss and sits in the office next to him. Also -- this "promotion" came out of the blue -- it was never mentioned that we were looking for a team manager it was announced in an email as a done deal.

I am not the only one who is upset about this...but we all feel our hands are tied.

Comment: Welcome to the Workplace -- I'm not sure we're going to be able to find an objective solution to this specific problem (is it ethical), which is also dependent on your specific company's policy. Can you focus your concern on something that might be able to be answered objectively and is more generally applicable?

Comment: This question as it stands is too broad.  I will say that you should plan your next move carefully.  Ask yourself what do you hope to gain by going to HR?  Do you think they will somehow fix the scenario?  You may be worse off after than you are now.

Comment: Related - https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/46269/2322

Comment: Sounds like an "assistant regional manager"...

Comment: @xiaomy "Assistant to the regional manager"

Comment: What you need to do is learn to play organizational politics.  Read several books on this.  The best you can hope for in this scenario right now is that you let the boss know you are interested in the next opportunity that comes along. But this is a done deal unless he does something (on his own without employee help) to prove he can't handle being a manager. However sabotaging him will not help get that result, so don't even think to go there.

Answer (score 6):

HR is not your friend, and Managers have a right to manage.

If this is how your boss wants to delegate his responsibilities then that is his prerogative. He's done nothing illegal, immoral, or even particularly out of the ordinary.

But it does make it clear that he intends to get his friend that promotion. So, if that's what your heart is set on, either look for an internal transfer, or start looking for a new job, because it's not happening here.

Answer (score 2):

He's being groomed for the position. It's a very common thing and there's really nothing you can do. Your boss can give assignments and he's given this one to him and directed you to deal with the coworker, even though he's not management. And yes, he will be given that promotion when it comes up because he already is doing the job.

You are all correct. Your hands are tied.  Since it's a large corporation, your only real recourse is to transfer out of that department. Sorry to be the confirmer of bad news.

As for HR, **HR is not your friend**. If you do go to HR, I can predict what will likely happen. HR will talk to your boss because you've made a complaint. Your boss will then find a way to get rid of you, either by transfer or termination. **Do not go to HR**